# matchesJsonPath throws warning as 2020-04-24 15:49:47.220 Warning: JSON path expression '$.xxx'

Tags: json, wiremock

### Bug reports

Added body in POST request as

```
"bodyPatterns": [
            { "matchesJsonPath": "$.xxx" },
            { "matchesJsonPath": "$.xxx" }
  ]
```

giving warning to all GET request as

`2020-04-24 15:49:47.220 Warning: JSON path expression '$.xxx' failed to match document 'null' because of error 'json string can not be null or empty'`

Please help we the issue

Comment: Show the complete definition. Seems like you also added this rule to GET requests. And as they have no body the validation obviously fails ...

Comment: @derpirscher I haven't added for get request. Its for POST request

Comment: Show your config. Obviously, it's trying to match the body also on GET requests ...